# Python on RPi: Errno 2 No such file or directory: 'config.json' but config.json is in the same folder as the main.py script

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi

*Hey all*

I am trying to run a python script from GitHub, https://github.com/dudisgit/gmod_toolgun_prop for a project with a functioning screen and I put a command at the end of the .bashrc file

```
python3 /home/pi/gmod_toolgun_prop-main/main.py
```

so that the code executes as soon as the RPi powers up. When running the script in Thonny's Python IDE on my RPi 2B it executes no problem and the screen works. However when I open terminal I get an error message from the code running in the .bashrc file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/gmod_toolgun_prop-main/main.py", line 381, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/gmod_toolgun_prop-main/main.py", line 357, in main
    with open(args.config) as config_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.json'
```

However, the **config.json file is in the same folder as the main.py file** as shown below:

[Screenshot of file explorer showing config.json is in the same folder as main.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvuyh.png)

[And here's a screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V28d.png)

And here's the code that is refenced in the error message as line 357:

```
with open(args.config) as config_file:
        config = json.load(config_file)
```

The entirety of the main.py script is in the Github link as attached in the first paragraph as well as the config.json file and other relevant files.

I am fairly new to the Python programming space so I don't understand what could be causing this error nor how this script handles opening the config.json file.

I have tried creating a custom service but it spits out the same error. Crontab and the local.bashrc file just doesn't work straight up for this. This is the furthest I have got with it attempting to execute on boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps to use the absolute path of config.json, i.e.(according to your description)

/home/pi/gmod_toolgun_prop-main/config.json

instead of the simple filename config.json.

Comment: How would I input the absolute path of the file when it doesn't have a area to input the file location? I am not heavily experienced in python and I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: Where / how in main.py is the .json file referred to / is it used as a parameter?

Comment: It is referenced as line 357 above in the question as with open(args.config) as config_file:
        config = json.load(config_file)

Comment: set there before:  config_file = '/home/pi/gmod_toolgun_prop-main/config.json'

(if this is the path to your config-file)

Comment: I have now done that and put it about the line of code but it stills spits out the same error, is there any other place should put the config.json directory location into?

Comment: Just looked into the source code on Github. There in main.py you can find: parser.add_argument("-config", default="config.json",
        help="The filepath to the json configuration")
which means you can specify the location of the son-file when starting the program. This way your .json-file can have any name you want and any location you want.
Try to start the application with a parameter on the command line

-config '/home/pi/gmod_toolgun_prop-main/config.json'

(if this is the path to your config-file)'

Comment: thanks so much that's made it work you're such a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

If Python says the file is not there, then the file is not there.  The only question is, where is *there*?

The filename in this case is **config.json**.  Since there's no `/` (no directory name), the name is taken to be relative to the current working directory.  That might or might not be the same as the directory of the main Python module, here **/home/pi/gmod_toolgun_prop-main/main.py**.

You can verify that by printing the current working directory just before opening the file.  You can use `os.getcwd` to do that.  Or, use **strace**(1) to show the interpreter's attempts to open **config.json**.

Comment: in python3: from os import getcwd; getcwd()

Comment: The working directory is /home/pi/gmod_toolgun_prop-main so it all is in the folder but why isn't it recognising it though?